# Why does Neo4j connection to Gephi error with Windows 10? (apoc.gephi.add)

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I keep getting the same error when trying to connect Gephi to Neo4j. What am I doing wrong?  I tried to reproduce the example from here: https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/neo4j-to-gephi/

**Environment Preparation:**

1. Installed the apoc.gephi.add from GitHub Step
2. Gephi:Installed add-in for Graph Streaming
3. Gephi: Master Server started (turns green )

**Reproduceable example**

in Neo4j:

4. Type ":play movies" into the cmd line $
5. click right arrow to load code into cmd line $
6. Now nodes and relationship types appear in Neo4j
7. Enter the code below:

   MATCH (p1:Person)-->(:Movie)<--(p2:Person) where id(p1) < id(p2)
   MERGE (p1)-[r:KNOWS]-(p2)
   ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1
   ON MATCH SET r.weight = r.weight + 1

   MATCH path = (:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(:Person)
   CALL apoc.gephi.add("http://localhost:7474",'WS1',path,'weight') yield nodes
   return *

[Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwRCR.png)
[Gephi Add-in turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dZ8v.png)

This should connect with Gephi and you should see a graph populate in Gephi. But I got this error:

> http://localhost:7474/WS1?operation=updateGraph as json: cannot retry
>   due to server authentication, in streaming mode
>   [Error mssg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcbKZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake in the apoc gephi procedure, you are using the Neo4j URL not the gephi one !

In this `apoc.gephi.add("http://localhost:7474",'WS1',path,'weight')` the url is wrong , it's not `http://localhost:7474` (the Neo4j one) but should be the one of Gephi server. Per default it's `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Excellent!  Solved!